# Redirecting pages in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project in React, and I am stuck on redirecting pages. Basically when I press the button
I am supposed to go into another page but for some reason, it's not working and I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./TaskBar.css";
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function TaskBar () {
    const history = useHistory();
    const navigateTo = () => history.push('/https://twitter-clone-react-d198a.web.app')
    
    return (
        <div className="taskbar">
            <button className="button"onClick={navigateTo}><img src="/icons/menu.icon.ico.png"/></button> 
        </div>
        )
}


export default TaskBar
```

Comment: I think `useHistory` returns undefined if you have : `<Route path="..." component={TaskBar}>`. it works only for children components of it. for this one, you can use : `this.props.history.push('/path')` instead of using `useHistory`. and for children you can use: `withrouter` or `useHistory`. also note that you can use `<a routerLink="..." >txt</a>` instead.

Comment: I have done it like this          <Router>
        <Link className="button" 
        onClick={() => {
          window.location.href = 'https://clone-react-9f63a.web.app/';
        }}
      >
  <img src="./icons/icons8-chrome-48.png"/>
      </Link>
 </Router>

Comment: sorry but it's not clean at all. does it navigate without refresh?

Comment: It does it fully

Comment: does it redirects without refresh?

Comment: as I have said it does

Answer (score 0):

useHistory hooks is based on react-router-dom if u have declared the route above link only it works or else it wont. for example u have 3 pages 1.Home,2.Edit,3.Add

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
 <Router>
              
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/Edit/:id" component={Edit} />
                    <Route path="/Add" component={Add} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
```

in your TaskBar component

```
   import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
function TaskBar () {

const history = useHistory();
const navigateTo = () => history.push('/')  //Home
const navigateTo = () => history.push('/Add')  //Add page
const navigateTo = () => history.push('/Edit/1')  //Edit page with id params

return (


 
    <div className="taskbar">
        <button className="button"onClick={navigateTo}><img src="/icons/menu.icon.ico.png"/></button> 
    </div>)}
```

**If u want go that page juz use anchor tag `<a href="/https://twitter-clone-react-d198a.web.app"><img src="/icons/menu.icon.ico.png"/></a>` or in by usingjavascript location.href**